# Is C++11 auto keyword exactly defined for all cases? Or: how does auto know what I intend?

Tags: c++, auto

Let's say, in C++11, I do

```
auto a = 4;
```

What will `a` be? An `int` (as I often read), an `unsigned int`, a `short`, a `long`, a `size_t`, a `char`? Is the behaviour of `auto` always defined, will it always be the exact same type (with the exact same bit length!) on each compiler and each architecture?

Another example:

```
class A{};
class B:A{};
auto x = new B();
```

Will `x` be of type `*B` or of type `*A`? Always the same on each compiler and platform? Both are perfectly legit, how does the compiler know which one I intend?

Is there an exact list of the `auto` behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it is always well defined. The expressions on the RHS resolve to a specific type, which is known at compile time.

Comment: @juanchopanza Thanks, but how do I find out what the variable type will be?

Comment: `int` is not the same length on all architectures/compilers. `4` is always an `int`.

Comment: @dyp `4` is always an `int`, but `123456` may be an `int` or a `long`.

Comment: @JamesKanze So, what does happen if I do `auto a = 123456;`? Is `a` of type `int` or `long`?

Comment: @Holt: `123456` will be `long` if that's large enough but `int` and `unsigned int` aren't (as specified by C++11 2.14/2, table 6).

Comment: @FooBar: `a` will be the same type as the literal `123456`; that type will be the smallest integer type that can represent the value, but no smaller than `int`.

Comment: The rules are the same as for template argument deduction. `template <class T> foo(T v); foo(4);` <- here `T` is `int`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> What will `a` be?

`int`, since that's the type of `4`.

> Will `x` be of type `*B` or of type `*A`?

`B*`, since that's the type of `new B()`.

> Is there an exact list of the `auto` behaviour?

Usually, it's the type of the initialiser; unless that's a reference type, in which case it's the underlying object type. There are a few other wrinkles for unusual types like arrays, as mentioned in the comments.

> will it always be the exact same type (with the exact same bit length!) on each compiler and each architecture?

In most cases, the initialiser has a well-defined type, and that determines the type deduced by `auto`.

If the initialiser is an integer literal, then the type might depend on the platform; for example, `1000000` might be `int` on a 32-bit platform, but `long` on a 16-bit platform.

Comment: Array-to-pointer conversion also applies, as well as the special case for braced-init-lists.

Comment: ...he says he over-simplified, but it's still the most detailed and accurate answer.

Answer (score 4):

Every expression in C++ has a type.  `auto` can only be used
when there is an initialization expression.  The type will be
the type of that expression.  The expression `4`, for example,
has type `int`, always, and the type of `new B()` is `B*`,
always.

Of course, the fact that the type is clear to the compiler
doesn't mean that it is clear to the reader.  Abuse of `auto` is
a good way of rendering a program unreadable, and also of making
it fragile, since the compiler cannot check whether they type of
the initialization expression is compatible with the desired
type.

Comment: There some cases where the type of the variable will not be the type of the expression, most prominently array-to-pointer conversion e.g. for string literals.

Comment: `auto` declays string literals?  I didn't know that!  It should totally be `const char(&)[`... oh.  `auto` gets rid of references.  Yeah, pointer decay makes sense then :(

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `a` will be a `int`, see bellow:

```
auto a = 4 ; // int
auto b = 4U ; // unsigned int
auto c = 4L ; // long int
auto d = 4LLU ; // unsigned long long int, maybe it's ULL i don't remember...
auto x = 4.0 ; // double
auto y = 4.0f ; // float
```

In fact, there is a way to write any 'type of' `int` in C.

For `new B()`, well the compiler will take the only answer, which is `B *`.

`auto` match the type of the right value the variable is assigned to, without trying to infer anything, it's not its job!

You should not see the `auto` keyword as a magic stuff, but just something than may help you in case you don't want to have big declaration type.

Comment: The compiler doesn't take the simplest answer, it takes the only answer.  And the only way of being sure of getting a `size_t` with `auto` is `auto a = static_cast<size_t>( 4 );` (or initializing it with some other expression which has a type of `size_t`).

Comment: @Holt: technically, there is one "quirk" with `auto`, that is removes references.  Not sure about const and volatile, it probably keeps those.

Comment: @MooingDuck: It removes  top level const/volatile also. `const int x = 100; auto y = x;` here `y` is `int`, not `const int`.... pretty much like template argument deduction.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler doesn't know what you intend, and it doesn't care. The type of a or x is the type of the expression on the right hand side. Since the type of 4 is int, and the type of new B() is B*, it's the same as if you wrote int a = 4; B* x = new B();